# RKManagedObjectRequestOperation Compiler complaines forward declaration when calling initialiser method 'initWithRequest:responseDescriptors'

Tags: objective-c, restkit, forward-declaration

Trying to use managed objects with `RestKit 0.23.3` and i get the following problem:

Compiler complains:

`Reciever 'RKManagedObjectRequestOperation' for class message is a forward declaration`

And

`Reciever type 'RKManagedObjectRequestOperation' for instance message is a forward declaration`

```
-(void)startOperation {
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [CPRObjectManager comprintObjectManager];
    NSURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:self.pathPattern parameters:self.requestParameters];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:self.mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:self.pathPattern keyPath:self.keyPath statusCodes:statusCodes];


    // This is straight from RK Docs: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit - Section: Managed Object Request
    // ERROR: http://gyazo.com/89ae7db26a367f0416c47549b6ea8cf3

    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[CPRPersistentStack sharedDataModel] objectStore];

}
```

Following the documentation: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit - Section: Managed Object Request it appears that the initWithRequest: responseDescriptors: is called as a class method of RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.

https://gist.github.com/wethu/2c6a7dfcbbc62af9dd36 full file includes are all there, anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after hours at this, I still have no clue why the compiler can't pick up the method signature for this initialiser. <strike>But I solved my problem by just adding:</strike>

`#import "RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.h"`

To my implementation file.

All the other RK classes found things just fine, I have no idea why this class needs its header file manually included outside of `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`.

**Edit:**

I wasn't satisfied with this solution, I dug even deeper and found that:

`Network.h` had this:

```
#ifdef _COREDATADEFINES_H
#import "RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.h"
#endif
```

Therefore checking that _COREDATADEFINES_H wasn't defined I found that my `<project>.pch` file had missing `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`

So the proper solution was to just add that to my pch file and it solved my problem.

I hope this helps someone else, it seems a little specific, however you never know who else follows this path and runs into this.

Answer (score 3):

If someone found this topic because it is related to Swift, solution for Swift implementation is to add it manually to Bridging Headers:

```
#import <RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.h>
```

because even if you did

```
import CoreData
```

RestKit cannot see that it was imported. I did not find any other solution for this.